# Enable An ActiveX TextBox When Selecting A OptionButton In Word 2007 Using VB

Tags: vb6, ms-word

I have a Word (2007) form which someone has created which has some VB in it for certain radio buttons, checkboxes, fields etc and i have been asked if i can make a change to it to enable/disable a textbox depending on an option selected from a radio button.

There are 3 options (1-3) for the question on the form, each with there own radio button.

The names are the default names (`OptionButton211`, `OptionButton221` & `OptionButton231`)

Below these are 2 ActiveX TextBoxes (`TextBox11` & `TextBox111`) which are both set to `Enabled = False` in VB when the document is first opened.

What is want is if option 2 radio button is selected (`OptionButton221`), they want one of the text boxes to be enabled and the other one still disabled.

I cant seem to figure it out.  I have tried the following but the textbox i want to be enabled is still disabled:

```
Private Sub TextBox11_Change()

If OptionButton221.Value = True Then
TextBox11.Enabled = True

Else TextBox11.Enabled = False
End If

End Sub
```

Sorry if this is in the wrong place.

Comment: Move your code to the OptionButton221_Click() event handler.

Comment: Thanks.  This worked great and as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki. Answer is in a comment. Anyone finding this topic in a search will see there is an answer and is more likely to look in for a hopefully useful answer.

"Move your code to the OptionButton221_Click() event handler." –  [jac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17776/jac)